# Qt Get char from hex

Tags: qt, char, hex

i have a QString with a hex code of one Char in it. I want to get the Char. 
I tried http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html#fromHex but fromHex needs a "const QByteArray". So

```
QByteArray value = QByteArray::fromHex( "70" ) ;
```

works, but

```
QByteArray value = QByteArray::fromHex( var ) ; //QString var = "70"
```

doesn't.
Is there any possibility to get the Char from the Hex-Code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try to call `QByteArray value = QByteArray::fromHex(var.toUtf8());`

Comment: What's `var` type? You can pass a non-const QByteArray as const QByteArray (or const reference). Just not vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `toInt` method with `base=16` specified as shown [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#toInt)

```
QString str = "70";
bool ok;
int hex = str.toInt(&ok, 16);
char value = (char)hex; // !
```